# What does it mean in log file: month: 1432

Tags: unix, timestamp

I came aross a log format (from a data management product called [Immuta](https://www.immuta.com/)) in Json which shows:

```
{
  "id": "5cbe96c0-70fa-11e9-996b-21bef380b159",
  "dateTime": "1557255621161",
  "month": 1432,
.....
}
```

What does it mean by 1432 in the month field?

there isn't much more info to provide here, I post it here in case my understanding is wrong, it seems this is a bug?

Thanks.

Comment: For all we know, this log came from an alien spaceship built in a star system that has many thousands of months in a year.

Comment: haha, no kidding, I am very serious asking this question.

Comment: I'm not kidding, though. I'm pointing out why your question is difficult to answer. You've far more information than we do here.

Comment: Ask Immuta what the log they create means. It's unlikely that anyone else will know what they mean.

Comment: Yes, that's what I plan to ask them, just don't want to ask silly question so I post it here first. I will post the response from Immuta as the anwser. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the application all we can do is guess, so, without further ado my guess.

1432 months is a little over 119 years (1428) which kinda, almost suggests that it is the number of months since January 1900 if you count that as month 1.

Comment: Thanks. Vendor replies it was mistakenly rolled out from legacy release which uses 1900 as the starting year.